# Laying down on the same bed

Tags: fiqh

Can Two men lay down on the same small bed ? I know that sleeping in the same bed is impermissible but is laying down also impermissible?
What if the man lays his hand on the chest of the other man. I am asking this because I read a story of two Ulama who layed down on the same small bed and one laid his hand on the others chest.

Comment: Why is sleeping in the same bed impermissible, what is your evidence?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong with it just as much as men sit down for a talk at the mosque and they sit close together. Or if two friends are sitting on the couch and are in close proximity with each other. Of course with separation between each other.

I cannot find any ruling unless they are sleeping under a cover with no barrier between them.

ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) Knows Best